# Can not reach a function after setting a breakpoint

Tags: assembly

I have the following problem:

I try to analyze a piece of code by using IDA PRO and Ollydbg. In IDA PRO, I see on the function graph image for example the function **sub_401985** and I decide to jump to that function and also analyze it in ollydbg.
In ollydbg, with a right click, I set a Toogle on **00401985** and press the Run-Button(F9) but ollydbg runs until the end and terminates.

Can someone explain to me why this happens?

edit: There are other subfunctions in the function at 00401985 which I can not analyze because of termination of the process.

Comment: Presumably because the function `sub_401985` isn't being called. The IDA call graph just means that it could be called. You'll have to look at the functions higher in the call graph to determine the circumstances necessary for it to be called.